# Transfer files from windows 10 computer to Linux server in the same machine?

Tags: file-transfer

No samba server. Any alternatives?

Problem statement: While installing ssl certificates, I need to copy paste in vi editor, where there's chance of extra space. That's why I want to transfer files directly to server from windows 10 server computer directly. Is there a way?

Comment: `scp` from Windows to Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the easiest way, use sftp. Maybe the above answers are trying to tell that, but they just spammed some random links!

```
sftp://user@ipaddress:port
```

Do this from file explorer path bar.

Comment: My answer was from research, not spam. You should spend some time knowing what you are talking about.  Of course there is more than one way to do things but your way does not invalidate others

Answer (score 1):

Two options (I use both and both methods work):

**(1) From Linux to Windows:**

Windows has SMB so in Linux:

`smb://192.168.x.y/folder`  (check IP of Windows machine)

This is easiest and works best. Once the mapping is complete, you can move files either way.

**(2) From Windows to Linux:**

You must install Samba on Linux.

[Install Samba](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#2-installing-samba)

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install samba
```

Make a directory to share:  `mkdir /home/<username>/sambashare`

Edit the smb.conf file:  `sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf`

Add the following lines at the bottom of the file:

```
[sambashare]

comment = Samba on Ubuntu

path = /home/<username>/sambashare

read only = no

browsable = yes
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the editor

Restart the samba service:   `sudo service smbd restart`

Update the firewall rules if necessary:  `sudo ufw allow samba`

`sudo smbpasswd -a <username>`   and password

(username must belong to a system account or it will not work)

In Linux:

```
smb://ip_address_of_Linux/sambashare
```

In Windows:

```
\\192.168.x.y where this is the IP of the Linux Machine
```

Authenticate with  and password

Shows as `sambashare` in Windows Explorer

Comment: Why use samba when there is scp?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to utilize Windows' implementation of OpenSSH

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration

this puts an SSH server on windows and puts it on level ground with linux, as this is how Linux systems typically interoperate anyway. And though that gives you some simple transfer methods like SFTP and SCP which will do what yu want, this will also allow you to use SSHFS. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSHFS

Using SSHFS, you can mount a ssh servers remote file system like a local directory, and put it anywhere you want it on the linux system you have RW access to.

Not necessarily better or worse than SMB, but a complexly viable way that opens new possibility at the same time.